# Ejecución js en cosola / visual studio code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

¿cómo puedo crear un archivo nuevo de js y/o ejecutarlos desde consola de visual studio code, sin necesidad de ir al navegador?
Gracias.

Comment: Javascript no se puede ejecutar sin un motor, por lo tanto necesitas NodeJS si no deseas ejecutarlo desde el motor del navegador.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el menu en la parte de arriba eliges `Terminal` y `Nueva Terminal`, ahí puedes probar archivos js, pero debes tener node instalado, tambien puedes abrit la terminal con el atajo de teclado `ctrl`+ `shift` + `ñ` o con [extensiones](https://medium.com/@maniakhitoccori/top-javascript-vscode-extensiones-para-un-desarrollo-m%C3%A1s-r%C3%A1pido-2351d7b0ae23)

Answer (score -1):

Existe la extensión [Live preview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.live-server). Con ella puedes abrir una ventana dentro de VS Code que muestra un modelo de la página que estás desarrollando.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).